# how can i run my code inside the ifstatement when i click the button

Tags: php, button, logging, if-statement

Hello guys i need a help in this code i want to do a user log that will output as a .txt
my problem is when i click the button. example VIEW button. the if statement below is not working.... dont know why..

im trying to call this code

```
echo '<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="mydata2.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" value="View">
</FORM>'; 

if( isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == "View") )
{   
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$updatefile = "userlogs.txt";
$fh = fopen($updatefile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "User: $username";
fwrite($fh, "$stringData".PHP_EOL);
$stringData = "Clicked View Button $date";
fwrite($fh, "$stringData".PHP_EOL);
fclose($fh);
}
```

sorry for the bad english.. i want to run the code above when you click the view button. did you guys get my point> ;/ i cant get it.. its not working

Comment: Is the PHP code above from `mydata2.php` or another file?

Comment: What isn't working? Does the if statement work? Is it trying to write the file and failing?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: JavaScript executes client-side, PHP server-side. You might want to look at [file_put_contents](http://us2.php.net/function.file-put-contents) with the `FILE_APPEND` flag.

Comment: yes sir mydata2.php is another file. I want to make a log that before i go to the mydata2.php the if statement will work so that it will be printed in the userlog.txt

Comment: it is not writing on the file when you click the button view

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Make sure that the folder and file have proper write permissions set. You can also try using `action=""` which is what I used instead of being pointed to a `.php` file. Use your entire code inside one file with opening and closing PHP tags and use `action=""` - The way you have it now, is hard to say if you are using `<?php` and `?>` tags. **Sample Output:** `User: 
Clicked View Button 2014-02-18 00:32:33
User: 
Clicked View Button 2014-02-18 00:34:04`

Comment: @Mrtata01 if you want someone to know you replied to them, type the `@` symbol and the person's name somewhere in your comment, like I did at the beginning of this one.

Comment: ...am left totally baffled. Didn't feel like worms tonite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**file1.php**

```
echo '<from method="POST" action="mydata2.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="View">
</form>';
```

**mydata2.php**

in this `$username` is not defined you should define it.

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == "View") )
{   
   $username = "your_username"; // define it

  $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $updatefile = "userlogs.txt";
  $fh = fopen($updatefile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
  $stringData = "User: $username";
  fwrite($fh, $stringData.PHP_EOL);
  $stringData = "Clicked View Button $date";
  fwrite($fh, $stringData.PHP_EOL);
  fclose($fh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code it is working. you might be missing your data. I have hardcoded  data.

```
 <?php

 echo '<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="mydata2.php">
 <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" value="View">
 </FORM>'; 

if( isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == "View") )
{

    $username = 'test';   
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $stringData = 'String data';
    $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $updatefile = "userlogs.txt";
    $fh = fopen($updatefile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "User: $username";
    fwrite($fh, "$stringData".PHP_EOL);
    $stringData = "Clicked View Button $date";
    fwrite($fh, "$stringData".PHP_EOL);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and working fine..see the changes I made.

```
<?php
  echo '<form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View">
        </form>'; 

if( isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == "View") )
{   
 $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $updatefile = "userlogs.txt";
 $fh = fopen($updatefile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
 $stringData = "User: ";
 fwrite($fh, "$stringData".PHP_EOL);
 $stringData = "Clicked View Button $date";
 fwrite($fh, "$stringData".PHP_EOL);
 fclose($fh);
}
?>
```